# alt+s not working as shown

Tags: modeling, edges

I´m quite new to Blender and I wanted to follow the new abandoned house tutorial posted by Blender Guru on Youtube.
At 2:34 he scales up the house using alt+s. But when I do it, the edges are creating some weird bulges instead of being straight like it's shown in the video.

Only scaling (s) the mesh is not working because I need to scale it along the normals.

[Youtube tutorial link](https://youtu.be/1aNnERnHRZg)

[image: how it should look like][image: how it looks like for me]

Comment: Hello and welcome, as far as I know, Alt + S is not to scale but to clear the scale. He probably made a mistake and did not edit that part or probably using a different shortcut or there is a step you did not see. But I'm not sure sure about it

Comment: Scale is simply _S_ (no Alt).

Comment: if you are referring to a video, you should add the link to the video....

Comment: Alt+S in object mode is used to clear the scale of an object whereas in edit mode it is a shortcut/hotkey used for the shrink/fatten tool. As Christopher Bennett mentioned in one of the comments just try scaling the edges. It should do the trick. Honestly, if I was a beginner I would not be following such a complicated tutorial in which he does not explain the whole workflow of creating a photorealistic scene in detail for beginners like you. This video is for intermediate or advanced blender users. It would be really helpful if shared your file.

Comment: It would be really helpful if shared your file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BlenderGuru abandoned house: Why does my shrink/fatten not work the way the tutorial does?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/243591/blenderguru-abandoned-house-why-does-my-shrink-fatten-not-work-the-way-the-tuto)