# BlenderGuru abandoned house: Why does my shrink/fatten not work the way the tutorial does?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, transforms

I was following Blender Guru's [Abandoned House tutorial](https://youtu.be/1aNnERnHRZg).  At 2:45 of the video/ my project I had to shrink/fatten the house up because of some mesh problems as instructed in the video. I was doing that but the problem was that the house became bloated and bendy. how do i not get it to bend and bloat?

[image]

[image: bloated house]

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241977/alts-not-working-as-shown ?

Comment: yes it's the same question....didnt notice it before...im new to blender.stackexchange....but yes...this is a duplicate.....

Answer (score 2):

This is because he probably missed one important information...
This happens if you do shrink/flatten by default:
[image]

I don't see him checking one value in tutorial... you have to check **Offset Even**:
[image]

After this it should work as intended (also I don't know if you did but use Ctrl+A and select Scale in Object mode before shrink/flatten

Comment: thanks...ill try it out and i'll let you know

Comment: i've tried the offset even thing out and it has made things better but it's still a little bit bendy but it'll do...thanks mate

Comment: Hmm it should't be bendy, can you show that file to me to check?

Comment: alright...but how do i do that?

Comment: Use this: https://blend-exchange.com/ place url of this question into it and your file

Comment: okay i uploaded it...do you see it?

Comment: Did you send me already shrinked version? Or this is what you had before shrinking?

Comment: no i had to fatten it and this is the already fattened version

Comment: and did you check offset even when you flattened it? Because this is probably result of it... if this is it than you need to either repair it manually or go back and do it correctly

Comment: i checked the offset....did it work for you?

Comment: @siddharthsubramaniam If you have fattened the house and it got bendy, it doesn't help if you fatten it again and check _Even Offset_ - it will not reverse the bending. You have to use it on a mesh with straight geometry.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this seeking the answer - Shft-d to duplicate The roof parts prior to seperating them, when you alt-s the house after boolean, after clicking look at the left corner, activate offset even then select the roof parts of the house model and gz them into place :)