# extruding wall tiles

Tags: mesh, modifiers, transforms

I was following Blender Guru's [Abandoned House tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aNnERnHRZg&t=154s). At 2:45 of the video/ my project I had to shrink/fatten the house up because of some mesh problems as instructed in the video. I was doing that but the problem was that the wooden panels extrude out of the house...the Boolean modifier was already turned on before the shrink/fatten and it worked fine....but it doesnt work after the shrink/fatten...how do i get it to work ?
[image]

[image: extruding wall tile things that isnt supposed to happen]

Comment: Hello, you don't have to ask the same question twice, if you want to, you could edit the original one and add more details to that one. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/243591/blenderguru-abandoned-house-why-does-my-shrink-fatten-not-work-the-way-the-tuto

Comment: it isnt the same question

Comment: yes, it is a part of the same project and the same timestamp but the problem is different

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BlenderGuru abandoned house: Why does my shrink/fatten not work the way the tutorial does?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/243591/blenderguru-abandoned-house-why-does-my-shrink-fatten-not-work-the-way-the-tuto)

Comment: no it doesnt answer it

Comment: Did you use shrink/fatten on the walls with the wooden panels? That's not what he does in the tutorial. Otherwise I have no idea how shrink/fatten on the other object included in the boolean modifier should make the panels extrude. I guess you should pay more attention to what is exactly done in the video, but nevertheless this is a tutorial for intermediate users, because he skips explaining a lot of basic things that you might be struggling with.